# Load two differents folders on the same port

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I would like to know if there is some way to do `tensorboard --logdir dir1` and `tensorboard --logdir dir2` without using two different ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Run `tensorboard --helpfull` and checkout the description of `logdir` argument:

> You may also pass a comma separated list of log directories, and TensorBoard
>       will watch each directory. You can also assign names to individual log
>       directories by putting a colon between the name and the path, as in
>
> ```
> tensorboard --logdir name1:/path/to/logs/1,name2:/path/to/logs/2
> ```

Comment: I think this should be `logdir_spec` instead of `logdir`.